# Adding you tube player (iFrame) in jQuery modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-dialog

I have some images in my `HTML` and _I need to play embedded you tube video videos on click of each image which should load/play in a [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default). Basically like a **pop up video player.**

So here is what i have done to play/attach video with each image. I have three images and i have added the unique video id in my custom `data-attribute` which i taken from you tube.

#### HTML

```
<div id="ImageBox">
 <img src="img1.png" class="playVideo" alt="" id="image1" data-videoId="v6jg8g"/>
 <img src="img2.png" class="playVideo" alt="" id="image2" data-videoId="re84hj"/>
 <img src="img3.png" class="playVideo" alt="" id="image3" data-videoId="dhj3fk"/>
</div>

<!-- HTML for jQuery modal dialog -->
<div id="MyVideoPlayer">
    <div>
        <strong id="videoTitle">title for video</strong>
        <img src="closeButton.png" id="Close" alt="Close" />
    </div>
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MyVideoId?wmode=opaque&autoplay=1&autohide=1&showinfo=0&controls=2&rel=0&enablejsapi=1" id="Player" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

> Note: I am using `iframe embed` method from [**you tube player
>   API**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Manual_IFrame_Embeds)
>   to embed videos.

For JavaScript/jQuery section, I came up with two choices here.

**1. Because i am working in a ASP.NET MVC 3 app, i can set the unique video id to `@ViewBag` in script and assign to `iFrame` like this...**

```
$('#ImagesBlock .playVideo').click(function(){
    var myId = $(this).attr('data-videoId');
    '@ViewBag.VideoId' = myId;
    $('#MyVideoPlayer').dialog(
        { width: 'auto' },
        { height: 'auto' },
        { draggable: false },
        { resizable: false },
        { closeOnEscape: false },
        { modal: true },
        { show: { effect: "fade", duration: 200} }
    });       
});
```

**2. Assign the updated `iFrame` src with new video id each time dialog
    opens.**

```
$('#imagesBlock .playVideo').click(function(){
    var myId = $(this).attr('data-videoId');

    var src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+ myId +'?wmode=opaque&autoplay=1&autohide=1
        &showinfo=0&controls=2&rel=0&enablejsapi=1';

    $('#MyVideoPlayeriframe').attr('src', src);     
    $('#MyVideoPlayer').dialog(
        { width: 'auto' },
        { height: 'auto' },
        { draggable: false },
        { resizable: false },
        { closeOnEscape: false },
        { modal: true },
        { show: { effect: "fade", duration: 200} }
    });        
});
```

Which one should I go with. I found some references though,

- [Embedded jwplayer into jQuery Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17804992/embedded-jwplayer-into-jquery-dialog)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887106/how-to-get-embedded-video-into-modal-dialog
- [jQuery mb.YTPlayer](http://plugins.jquery.com/jquery.mb.YTPlayer/)

Is there any way i can make it little more simplified and re-usable in future. Please advise with your wise opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am little late updating this thread but I managed to create a method or more of a plugin by [extending jQuery's prototype object](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/). This is a nice link to [start learning](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/).

```
// following is the method by extending the jQuery's prototype object
// to convert and embed an element into a video pop-up
(function ($) {

    $.fn.videoPlayer = function (options) {

        var defaults = $.extend({
            title: "",
            videoId: "",
            autoplay: 1
        }, options);

        var videoBox = this.find('#VideoBox');
        var videoElement = document.createElement('iframe');
        var src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + defaults.videoId + '?wmode=opaque&autoplay=' + defaults.autoplay + '&autohide=1&showinfo=0&controls=2&rel=0&enablejsapi=1';

        this.find('#VideoTitle').text(defaults.title);
        $(videoElement).attr({
            'src': src,
            'frameborder': 0,
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '90%'
        });

        videoBox.html(videoElement);

        this.dialog(
            { width: 'auto' },
            { height: 'auto' },
            { draggable: false },
            { resizable: false },
            { closeOnEscape: false },
            { modal: true },
            { show: { effect: "fade", duration: 200} },
            { hide: { effect: "fade", duration: 250} },
            { close: function (event, ui) {
                $(videoElement).remove();
                $(this).dialog('destroy');
              }
            });

        //making the method chainable!
        return this;
    };

})(jQuery);


$(function(){

  $('#VideoPlayerPopUp #Close').click(function () {
    $("#VideoCatcher").dialog("close");
  });

  $('#Entertainment .launch-video').click(function () {
    var element = $(this);

    $('#VideoCatcher').videoPlayer({
       title: element.attr('data-videoTitle'),
       videoId: element.attr('data-videoId')
    });
  });
});
```

I have used custom HTML [data-attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) for video title and video id. This will keep HTML clean and semantic. You can of course style/customize the pop-up accordingly.

Visit [**this working demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/nhy67q2d/1/) to see this in action.